# Is it possible to use Declare inside of a CTE?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to execute below code:

```
;with cte  as 
(  
    select 
        convert(varchar(50), joiningdate, 101) as joindate 
    from 
        employeedetail   
)   
declare @dateuse varchar(200)=cte.joindate  
select datediff(dd, @dateuse, GETDATE()) 
from cte
```

but it shows an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 909
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'.

I want to use variable which hold the joindate values and return values according to that. How?

Comment: Why cant you just calculate in the select query i.e.`with cte as (...) select datediff(dd,joindate,getdate()) from cte`?

Comment: yes i can do this by your suggestion, but i want to do this by using variable

Comment: But the question really is: **why** are you converting what appears to be a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column to a `VARCHAR(50)` first, and then you want to use it inside a `DATEDIFF` function - that makes **no sense** at all ! Just leave the column as `DATE`/`DATETIME` and apply `DATEDIFF` to it....

Comment: Most people would expect that `employeedetail` is a table containing *multiple* rows, and as such, would expect the CTE to (potentially) return *multiple* rows. So in what way would it make sense to assign `joindate`, as returned by the CTE, to a *scalar* variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use declare in a script, procedure, or UDF. Can't be used in queries or views.

In this case it seems like you don't even need a CTE or type conversion. This query will tell you how many days the employee has been around which seems like the objective:

```
select datediff(dd, joningdate, getdate()) from employeedetail
```